# How to hook into MMenu event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mmenu

I've successfully added a Search facility for the MMenu jquery plugin.  It's working great except for one thing: When the Search For textbox appears, I want to set focus to it.  So far I've accomplished this by adding an 'onmouseover' event handler to the parent of the textbox which is the 'ul' representing the "page" currently visibly.  It kind of works but is kludgy because the user needs to move the cursor over the designated area.  On a mobile device, I doubt it would work at all

I'm looking for a way to hook into MMenu's event handler that opens the page that the Search textbox is on.  Here's an example of the HTML code I'm dealing with:

```html
<nav id="menu" class="mm-menu mm-horizontal mm-offcanvas mm-current mm-opened">
<ul id="mm-0" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-opened mm-subopened">
<ul id="mm-1" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-highest mm-current mm-opened">
<li class="mm-subtitle">
      Search for:  
<input id="search" type="text" onkeyup="HandleSearchInput(this);" size="20">
<br>
<div id="searchResults" style="margin:10px 10px 0 20px">
</ul>
<ul id="mm-2" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-3" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-4" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-5" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-6" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-7" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-8" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-9" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-10" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-11" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-12" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-13" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
<ul id="mm-14" class="mm-list mm-panel mm-hidden">
</nav>
```

Might anyone know how to do this?

Robert W.

Answer (score 0):

As per the new [mmenu](https://mmenujs.com/) version and by using [its off-canvas hooks](https://mmenujs.com/docs/core/off-canvas.html) you can achieve this. 
 
**HTML**

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>            
        <li><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search..."></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        new Mmenu( "#menu",{
            hooks:{
                open:finish: () => {
                    $('#search').focus();
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```